# flutter animation stops executing after 6 execution

Tags: flutter, dart

I am creating an ease in and ease out animation that takes place repeatedly and a container widget eases in - pauses - and then eases out. I have created the animation and it is doing fine but after 6 execution it gets stopped! I have tried to put the second listener in its own method and then use removeListener but it was not useful either.
any suggestion or idea would be very appreciated.
here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(primaryColor: Colors.red),
      home: EaseAnimation(),
    );
  }
}

class EaseAnimation extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _EaseAnimationState createState() => _EaseAnimationState();
}

class _EaseAnimationState extends State<EaseAnimation>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  Animation _animation;
  AnimationController _controller;
  @override
  void initState() {
    void listener(status) {
      if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
        _animation.removeStatusListener(listener);
        _controller.reset();
        _animation = Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(
            CurvedAnimation(parent: _controller, curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn))
          ..addStatusListener((status) {
            if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
              _controller.reset();
              _animation = Tween(begin: -1.0, end: 0.0).animate(CurvedAnimation(
                  parent: _controller, curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn))
                ..addStatusListener(listener);
              _controller.forward();
            }
          });
      }
    }

    _controller =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(seconds: 2));
    _animation = Tween(begin: -1.0, end: 0.0).animate(
        CurvedAnimation(parent: _controller, curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn))
      ..addStatusListener(listener);
    _controller.forward();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: _controller,
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: Transform(
            transform:
                Matrix4.translationValues(_animation.value * width, 0.0, 0.0),
            child: Center(
                child: Container(
              height: 200,
              width: 200,
              color: Colors.black,
            )),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: nesting animation listeners one into another seems like a terrible idea to me. Are you trying to drive the animation from `-1.0` to `1.0`, then reverse from `1.0` to `-1.0`, and repeat?

Comment: I am trying to animate from -1 to 0 then from 0 to 1 and then repeat.(-1=>0 ,0=>1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick but destructive solution is to change `if` condition in the `listener` to:

```dart
if (status == AnimationStatus.completed || status == AnimationStatus.dismissed) {
```

However, the way animation is designed will bring a lot of problems. It does cause trouble already, in fact.

The reason animation gets stuck is because it nests one animation listener into another, entering a sort of locked infinite loop that Flutter tries to dispose.

---

I would recommend to design custom animation curve using [Cubic](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/Cubic-class.html) class. e.g.

```dart
Cubic(0, 1, 1, 0)
```

This simple curve will stall the animation in the middle of its progress.

Now, we can modify your code to something way simpler - like this:

```dart
void listener(status) {
  if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
    _controller.forward(from: 0);
  }
}

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  _controller = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(seconds: 4));
  _animation = Tween(begin: -1.0, end: 1.0).animate(
      CurvedAnimation(parent: _controller, curve: const Cubic(0, 1, 1, 0))
    )
    ..addStatusListener(listener);

  _controller.forward();
}
```

This will render a black box that starts on the left, proceeds to the center of the screen, pauses, then resumes to the end of the screen, and repeats.

If the curve I suggested is not suitable in your case - [this link](https://cubic-bezier.com/#0,1,1,0) will help you design your own custom one, as well as help understand Cubic Bezier curves in general.

Let me know if this helped.